# what does this symbol mean in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, business-objects, archimate

what does this little infinity like symbol mean in Enterprise Architect?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's an indicator for a composite diagram. You can dbl-click the element to open the diagram. From the element's contex menu you can choose a different diagram

[image]

(might look different for different elements)